# Dynamic cloning when creating boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, code-duplication, cloning

I have an issue that I can't seem to resolve. Even though my current job does not call for integration, I have been doing a bit of it for a specific project.

BACKGROUND: 
Basically, this is what I am currently working on: when I click on my fake button, it creates a box - more clicks, means more boxes which are created. However, the boxes need to be able to do one more thing than simply replicate - each one of them needs to allow me to drag and drop an image into them. So, if I click 5 times on the fake button, the 5 new boxes needs to allow me to drag and drop 5 different images. Currently, I have a box there by default (as a testing ground).

PROBLEM:
I cannot seem to duplicate the boxes correctly. I have tried several things, including switching classes to id's and what not to try and merge several pieces of coding together. Ultimately, I need to be able to place any images in the draggable boxes. 5 boxes, 5 images dragged into them etc.

NOTE 1:
I cannot use server-side coding, as I don't have access to the server. All of it has to be client side.

NOTE 2:
The images I bring in are from outside folders - from the desktop (dragged and dropped).

NOTE 3:
I watered down the code in the fiddle to only have the pieces of coding relevant to what I am attempting to do. However, the scripts there don't work within the fiddle, since I had to take them out of the environment. Though, they do work within the correct environment.

FIDDLE:
[My link]    https://jsfiddle.net/t9dq3w28/10/

```
...
```

Comment: seems you need to add the `ondrag*` handlers to the newly created "boxes"

Comment: @JaromandaX Assuming I add ondrag handlers, are those not for content already on the web? I am not sure sure I understand how ondrag handlers  would help in this case, in terms of the creation of new boxes possessing the ability of being able to drag and drop items from the desktop. Unless I am missing something - as I not very familiar with dragging capabilities using js.